# Difference between Long.toString(i) vs i + ""

Tags: java, string

we often come across a scenario where in we need to pass a String representation of a primitive and More often then not we use

```
  WrapperClass.toString() ;
```

and sometimes we usually write

```
  i + "";
```

if we check to toString implementation of any wrapper class it creates a new String object every time we call it. and same is also true for  primitive + ""  (as Concatenation during runtime will create new String Object)

So is there any difference between them or they are just an alternative ways to  convert a primitive to a String object;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good intentions.

Writing `i + "";`, you're possibly leaving it up to your code's future maintainer (which could very well be you) to figure out what that output will be.

`WrapperClass.toString();` is more explicit and, although more verbose, its intentions are clearer. Besides, [weak typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing) isn't what you'd normally see in Java, so I suggest you stick to writing idiomatic Java code.

After compilation, emitted bytecode will most likely be the same or similar. After jitting and during runtime, you can expect the differences to be effectively nullified.

So, at the end, it's a matter of style, although I'd suggest using the more verbose version of your code.

Comment: isn't there a difference in performance ? as if you look into implemention of WrapperClass.toString() its doing lot of processing viz( creating a char[], and looping over it) where as i think primitive + ""  does new String () behind the scenes ?

Comment: @Dhirendra: It is highly unlikely that this is going to be your performance bottleneck.  If it *is* a performance bottleneck, it will probably be a bottleneck as used in one specific function (determined by a profiler), which you can tweak as necessary, with careful documentation explaining why.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I like [`String.valueOf(i)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29):

- You can use it with all types (even non-primitives)
- It's null-safe (assuming you're happy with a string value of "null" when converting a value of null)
- It expresses your intention far better than `"" + i` - that code expresses string concatenation, which isn't what you're after at all.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally, they are the same. The difference is, that `i + "";` is basically using a side-effect to archive its purpose, which might make it more difficult to understand for beginners.